# slideToggle() function of jquery not stable

Tags: jquery, button, accordion

I am using the following code http://jsfiddle.net/stXP6/ for hiding and showing contents using slideToggle. Here the code works fine. But when I have integrated with my code its behaving weird. When
I click on the button the content toggles multiple times and then becomes stable after a while.

I have written a code that when I click on the accordion some of the contents remain hidden. But when person clicks on the button then they becomes visible. I have kept javascript content as on http://jsfiddle.net/stXP6/ inside the function for click on any accordion option.

Have anybody experience such problem? what should I do it to make it stable.

Comment: Your links are pointing to same fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [clearQueue](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) and [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(".test").hide();
$(".toggleButton").click(function() {     
    $(this).next(".test").slideToggle("slow", function(){ //Wait until action is complete
        $(this).next(".test").clearQueue(); //Clears animation Queue
        $(this).next(".test").stop(); //Stops all actions
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I got error saying: Type Error undefined is not a function (evaluating $(this)). The error is right after line $(this).next(".test").slideToggle("slow", function(){